# What is happening when I declare an int, double, and char; I input a double for an int and an int for a double? It seems as it breaks things apart

Tags: char, integer, double

input: 5.7  4  b

output: 5 0.7 4

What is happening for this output to occur?
Also I notice that I am unable to input the last varble "char" when I use inputs that don't match their declared data type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int whole;
    double fractional;
    char letter;

    cin >> whole >> fractional >> letter;
    cout << whole << " " << fractional << " " << letter << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at first cin expects an integer, so it only reads the integer part of the first value and leaves the rest. Your input is equivalent to this 5 0.7 4 b, so b is never read.

Comment: Thank you @daskalgg. What I don't struggle to understand is that from the code we ask for three different entries cin << int << double << char. I thought the system reads the input of each entry once the user types it in the terminal and hits enter or spacebar. It appears that I could input all three entries in the first entry line of the code.  For example: I could terminal input: 5.7b and it will output: 5 .07 b    or    input: 5.7  b output: 5 0.7 b